# Oracle ROWTOCOL Function oddities

Tags: database, oracle

I have a requirement to pull data in a specific format and I'm struggling slightly with the ROWTOCOL function and was hoping a fresh pair of eyes might be able to help.

I'm using 10g Oracle DB (10.2) so LISTAGG which appears to do what I need to achieve is not an option.

I need to aggregate a number of usernames into a string delimited with a '$' but I also need to concatenate another column to to build up email addresses.

```
select
rowtocol('select username_id from username where user_id = '||s.user_id|| 'order by USERNAME_ID asc','@'||d.domain_name||'$') 
from username s, domain d
where s.user_id = d.user_id
```

(I've simplified the query specific to just this function as the actual query is quite large and all works except for this particular function.)

in the DOMAIN Table I have a number of domains such as 'hotmail.com','gmail.com' etc

I need to concatenate the username, an '@' symbol followed by the domain and all delimited with a '$'

such as ......

```
joe.bloggs@gmail.com$joeblogs@gmail.com$joe_bloggs@gmail.com
```

I've battled with this and I've got close but in reverse?!.....

```
gmail.com$joe.bloggs@gmail.com$joeblogs@gmail.com$joe_bloggs
```

I've also noticed that if I play around with the delimiter (,'@'||d.domain_name||'$') it has a tendency to drop off the first character as can be seen above the preceding '@' has been dropped from the first email address.

Can anyone offer any suggestions as to how to get this working?

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `rowtocol` a string aggregation function you've written?

Comment: Hi Alex, no, I've not compiled this myself it's the standard function built into oracle as far as I'm aware.

Comment: It isn't a built-in function. If you didn't write it, someone in your company did, and made it generally available. (It might be based on [the one here](https://community.oracle.com/message/3912765#3912765), though the original Oracle Magazine article is no longer found; there seem to be other versions with the same name if you search).

Comment: I discovered the function a while ago and just assumed it was a built in function, that's my misunderstanding.

Comment: It doesn't really matter - from my initial reading of the question I thought there was a problem with your function and we'd need to see it's source code; but as the problem is actually how it's being called, it doesn't matter so much exactly how the function is written. Other than for curiosity and to reproduce your results. Incidentally, it would be helpful if you included the table structures and sample data in the question, also to make it easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [the `rowtocol` function from OTN](https://community.oracle.com/message/3912765#3912765), and have tables something like:

```
create table username (user_id number, username_id varchar2(20));
create table domain (user_id number, domain_name varchar2(20));

insert into username values (1, 'joe.bloggs');
insert into username values (1, 'joebloggs');
insert into username values (1, 'joe_bloggs');
insert into domain values (1, 'gmail.com');
```

Then your original query gets three rows back:

```
gmail.com$joe.bloggs
gmail.com$joe_bloggs@gmail.com$joebloggs
gmail.com$joe_bloggs@gmail.com$joebloggs
```

You're passing the data from each of your user IDs to a separate call to `rowtocol`, which isn't really what you want. You can get the result I think you're after by reversing it; pass the main query that joins the two tables as the select argument to the function, and have that passed query do the username/domain concatenation - that is a separate step to the string aggregation:

```
select
rowtocol('select s.username_id || ''@'' || d.domain_name from username s join domain d on d.user_id = s.user_id', '$')
from dual;
```

which gets a single result:

```
joe.bloggs@gmail.com$joe_bloggs@gmail.com$joebloggs@gmail.com
```

Whether that fits into your larger query, which you haven't shown, is a separate question. You might need to correlate it with the rest of your query.

There are other ways to string aggregation in Oracle, but this function is one way, and you already have it installed. I'd look at alternatives though, such as ThomasG's answer, which make it a bit clearer what's going on I think.

Comment: Hi Alex, This is so frustrating as my original plan was to concatenate the two columns within the rowtocol query and then delimiting with just '$' and the query failed repeatedly and I eventually made an assumption that the rowtocol function didn't allow Joins but it looks like it could have just been syntax errors on my part with the apostrophes used to quote the '@' sybmol. That's why I attempted to concatenate what I needed within the area used to specify the string used to delimit the values.

Comment: I've made some tweaks as I need to apply logic to the query to deal with eventualities where one column will return a NULL and in that case it needs to still provide another column so have used an NVL to concatenate another string. I've been struggling with this now on and off for a couple of days so I'm over the moon I can down tools for the XMAS hols knowing I can deliver the dataset as promised! Many Thanks for taking the time out on this, it's very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex told you in comments, this ROWTOCOL isn't a standard function so if you don't show its code, there's nothing we can do to fix it.

However you can accomplish what you want in Oracle 10 using the XMLAGG built-in function.

try this :

```
SELECT 
    rtrim (xmlagg (xmlelement (e, s.user_id || '@' || d.domain_name || '$')).extract ('//text()'), '$') whatever
FROM username s
INNER JOIN domain d ON  s.user_id = d.user_id
```

Comment: Thomas, thanks for your time in responding, I've tried this and it worked well however when I've tried to add it to my overall query I hit a snag in that I had to use a group by for another column, but I also needed to do an NVL on teh statement and the other value I wanted in case of a NULL complains about the group by.